# json multidimensional array jquery

Tags: jquery, json, multidimensional-array

Pulling my hair out here, i know it' the structure of how JSOn works.

There is a multidimensional array that is undefined from a web API. 
structure is

```
{
"totalCount": 30,
"entries": [{"title": "item1","description": "your amazing item 1"}], 
"price": [{"value": "$23.34","discount": "none"}],
"newINfo" = 20
},
{
"entries": [{"title": "item2","description": "your amazing item 2"}], 
"price": [{"value": "$23.34","discount": "none"}],
"newINfo": = 50
},
```

Jquery > if i set $.each(data, to>  $.each(data.entires and remove the entires from where its called on the content string, it works one at a time, but then the array items are not linked.

```
$.getJSON('/theWebApi', function (data) {
    var content = '';
    $.each(data, function(i, object) {
        content += '<div>' + object.entires.title + '</div>';
        content += '<div>' + object.price.value + '</div>';
    });
    $(content).appendTo(".test")
 });
```

Comment: explain more.., Question is confusing..

Comment: There is an error in your json. `"newINfo" = 20` should be `"newINfo" : 20`

Comment: @jitendra so im trying to access the API to display information on my page. the API is a separate entity that can not be changed. there is currently around 30 records in there, that are going to scale up. 

i can access individual multidimensional array elements by specifying data.entries, however the whole array item is then not linked, so i can't call price, name, description etc together.

Comment: @AdityaParab was just me writing it wrong here, not an error, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `entries` and `price` are `Array` so you won't be able to do `object.entries.title` directly. You're gonna have to iterate over `entries` and `price` properties like,

```
$.getJSON('/theWebApi', function (data) {
    var content = '';
    $.each(data, function(i, object) {
        $.each(object.entries, function(k, v){
            content += '<div>' + v.title + '</div>';
        });
        $.each(object.price, function(k, v){
            content += '<div>' + v.value + '</div>';
        });
    });
    $(content).appendTo(".test")
 });
```

Comment: tried this, getting an error in the consol "jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: Got it, was a semi-colon in the wrong place, always the smallest of things, thank you for your help, much appreciated it. your logic was very sound and helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to

```
{
    "totalCount": 30,
    "entries": {"title": "item1","description": "your amazing item 1"}, 
    "price": {"value": "$23.34","discount": "none"},
    "newINfo" = 20
},
{
    "entries": {"title": "item2","description": "your amazing item 2"}, 
    "price": {"value": "$23.34","discount": "none"},
    "newINfo" = 50
},
```

Comment: can't change the api, wish i could, its very poorly written

Comment: Then try entries[0].title and price[0].value. This should work assuming that are only one entry is expected entries.

Answer (score 0):

This might help!

```
$.getJSON('/theWebApi', function (data) {
  var content = '';

  $.each(data, function(i, v) {
    $.each(v.entries, function(j, entry) {
      $.each(v.price, function(j, price) {
        content += '<div>'+ entry.title +'</div>';
        content += '<div>'+ price.value +'</div>';
      });
    });
  });

  $('.test').append(content);
});
```